# Should I Append or Join a list of dict and And how in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, join, append

Using this code I was able to cycle through several instances of attributes and extract First and Last name if they matched the criteria. The results are a list of dict.  How would i make all of these results which match the criteria, return as a full name each on it's own line as text?

```
my_snapshot = cfm.child('teamMap').get()
for players in my_snapshot:
    if players['age'] != 27:
    print({players['firstName'], players['lastName']})
```

**Results of Print Statement**

```
{'Chandon',  'Sullivan'}
{'Urban', 'Brent'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
 print(players['firstName'], players['lastName'])
```

> This would output:
>
> ```
> Chandon Sullivan
> Urban Brent
> ```

Your original trial just put the items to a set `{}`, and then printed the set, for no apparent reason.

Edit:

You can also for example join the `firstName` and `lastName` to be one string and then append the combos to a lists. Then you can do whatever you need with the list:

```
names = []
my_snapshot = cfm.child('teamMap').get()
for players in my_snapshot:
    if players['age'] != 27:
        names.append(f"{players['firstName']} {players['lastName']}")
```

If you're using a version of Python lower than 3.6 and can't use `f-strings` you can do the last line for example like this:

```
names.append("{} {}").format(players['firstName'], players['lastName'])
```

Or if you prefer:

```
names.append(players['firstName'] + ' ' + players['lastName'])
```

Comment: You are correct.  It displays correctly in the console but when try to pass `players['firstName'], players['lastName']` to a device it only shows the last found record.  So I was trying to figure out how how I would join each record so that it could be sent to the device displaying all of the found records.

Comment: @WillJames what do you mean by passing to a device?

Comment: thanks I figured it out last night and I put my solution below.

Comment: @WillJames feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you feel that it provided a good solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out by appending the first and last name and creating a list for the found criteria.  I then converted the list to a string to display it on the device.

```
    full_list = []

    my_snapshot = cfm.child('teamMap').get()
    for players in my_snapshot:
        if players['age'] != 27:
        full_list.append((players['firstName'] + " " + players['lastName']))

    send_message('\n'.join(str(i) for i in full_list))
```